# How to clear current “read-only” state on a USB flash drive I setup with Rufus?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Three weeks ago I used [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie) 2.2 to install Windows 10 on my machine, and it has write-protected my flash drive.
I’ve tried `diskpart`:

```
diskpart
att disk clear readonly 
clean
create partition primary
format fs=fat32 quick
```

And it kinda worked, it removed the image off the USB, but now it’s showing:

```
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
```

And I can’t format it or write on it.

The drive is a a Kingston DataTraveler G4 32GB model, without physical switches. How would I restore it back to normal (`rw`) state?

Comment: From @SSI: Does this article help you to solve the issue: http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/54---how-to-fix-write-protected-disks

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer, but this should solve and does not require 3rd party apps: diskpart ; list disk ; select disk ; clean ; create partition primary ; format fs=ntfs quick

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve with RMPrepUSB https://www.rmprepusb.com/ and I had the issue with an SD card I wanted to erase.

Comment: Can we get more information on how this was done?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I simply wiped the card removing the partitions that I could not delete with the native tools in windows. To do that use the button "prepare unit" that wipes it and creates a new partition

Comment: or do it with cli diskpart ; list disk ; select disk ; clean ; create partition primary ; format fs=ntfs quick