# Where is StorageDevicePolicies in Windows 10's registry?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I have the same problem as stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/972015/how-to-clear-current-read-only-state-on-a-usb-flash-drive-i-setup-with-rufus). One of the answers proposes modifying the registry, but unfortunately, I can't find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies` in the registry. Is it anywhere else in Windows 10?

Comment: That Is the correct location.  Home or Professional?

Comment: @Ramhound Home version

Answer (score 2):

Mark Control then go to File & make a new key which name is StorageDevicePolicies after making that make a DWORD (32-bit) Value. Then you will be find this file. Best of luck.
*In Windows 10 you have to make it.